# How do I use an instance of a class in another file in another class?

Tags: python, class, oop, import

## inside main.py file

```
from Level_Class import Level
from Player_Class import Player

level = Level(level_map)
```

## inside Level_Class.py file

```
class Level:
    def __init__(self, map):
        self.tile_list = []

        for row_index, row in enumerate(map):
            for col_index, col in enumerate(row):
                # print(row_index, col_index, col)
                if col == "X":
                    tile_surf = pygame.Surface((100, 100))
                    tile_rect = tile_surf.get_rect()
                    tile_surf.fill("Grey")
                    tile_rect.x = col_index * 100
                    tile_rect.y = row_index * 100
                    # print(tile_rect.x, tile_rect.y)
                    tile = (tile_surf, tile_rect)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)
# the only important part is the self.tile_list
```

## inside Player_Class.py file

```
from main import level




class Player():
    def __init__....

def update(self):

for tile in level.tile_list:
    if tile[1].colliderect(self.player_rect.x + diff_x, self.player_rect.y, 100, 100):
        diff_x = 0
```

cannot import name 'Player' from partially initialized module 'Player_Class' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\archi\PycharmProjects\5Game\Player_Class.py)

My question is how do I use an instance of the class Level in main.py and use that in another class' function which is in another file? I wonder if I can use inheritance in some way but I am not sure if that will
Im kinda new to python so sorry about the weird format.

My question is how do I use an instance of the class Level in main.py and use that in another class' function which is in another file? I wonder if I can use inheritance in some way but I am not sure if that will
Im kinda new to python so sorry about the weird format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Player_Class.py` file imports level from `main.py`, which imports Player from `Player_Class.py`. That results in circular import. You have to carefully check your imports and (if you can't remove any) place some of them in nested scope (inside class functions or somewhere)